# Paramaterised stored procedure in SQL Server - error "Ambiguous column name 'musictypeID'"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have been working on paramaterised stored procedure in SQL Server, but I get an error stating

> Ambiguous column name 'musictypeID'

Code:

```
create procedure getmusicbytype
    (@musictypeID int)
as
begin
    select * 
    from musicc 
    inner join MusicType on musicc.musictypeID = MusicType.musictypeID
    where musictypeID = @musictypeID
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Both tables have `musictypeID`, so you need to specify one in the `where` clause.

Change `where musictypeID = @musictypeID` to `where musicc.musictypeID = @musictypeID`